# Have a program that I would like to fuse a merge sort into but having trouble doing so

Tags: java, arrays, reference, comparator, mergesort

I had three classes of a program that took a bunch of data and sorted it using comparators. What i did was I added a merge sort at the end of the class called EarthquakeDataSet. The merge is added down there was one that worked with an array of ints. What i want to do is work with an array of references from EarthquakeRecord. Then I need the comparison to work with it as well. The merge starts at the end of class EarthquakeDataSet at private int[] data. Any suggestions would be appreciated

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class EarthquakeTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EarthquakeDataSet eqds = new EarthquakeDataSet(); 
    String sFileName = null;
    try {
        File file;
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fc.getSelectedFile();

            long lElapseTime = eqds.loadDataFromFile(file);// open file and parse all data into <i>EarthquakeRecord</i> objects
            System.out.println("File Loading / Parsing: Elapsed time: " + ((float) lElapseTime) / 1000.0);

            lElapseTime = eqds.copyOriginalArray();
            System.out.println("Create 3 copies of arrays: Elapse Time: " + ((float) lElapseTime) / 1000.0);

            eqds.sortNativeJava(); // a batch process akin to the Google batch process of building a planetary index of the internet

            System.out.println("Data After Sorting with Native Java Sort");
            while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Display Sorted View?") == 0)
                eqds.display(); // allow user to view the data multiple times and view the outcome of the sort: akin to Google users performing lookups
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found: " + sFileName);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO Exception: " + sFileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: General Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Comparator;



public class EarthquakeRecord {
private int nYear;
private int nMonth;
private int nDay;
private int nHour;
private int nMinute;
private double dSecond;
private int nUTC;
private double dLatitude;
private double dLongitude;
private double dMagnitude;
private int nDepth;
private int nEpicentre;
private double dCityLatitude;
private double dCityLongitude;
private String sCityName;

public EarthquakeRecord(String sRawRecord) { parseStringInput(sRawRecord); }


private void parseStringInput(String sRawRecord) {
    try {
        nYear = Integer.parseInt(sRawRecord.substring(0, 4));
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nYear = 0;
    }
    try {
        nMonth = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(5, 7)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nMonth = 0;
    }
    try {
        nDay = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(8, 10)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nDay = 0;
    }
    try {
        nHour = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(11, 13)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nHour = 0;
    }
    try {
        nMinute = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(14, 16)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nMinute = 0;
    }
    try {
        dSecond = Double.parseDouble((sRawRecord.substring(17, 21)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        dSecond = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        nUTC = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(23, 25)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nUTC = 0;
    }
    try {
        dLatitude = Double.parseDouble((sRawRecord.substring(30, 37)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        dLatitude = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        dLongitude = Double.parseDouble((sRawRecord.substring(38, 46)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        dLongitude = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        dMagnitude = Double.parseDouble((sRawRecord.substring(46, 49)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        dMagnitude = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        nDepth = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(50, 54)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nDepth = 0;
    }
    try {
        nEpicentre = Integer.parseInt((sRawRecord.substring(56, 61)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        nEpicentre = 0;
    }
    try {
        dCityLatitude = Double.parseDouble((sRawRecord.substring(62, 71)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        dCityLatitude = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        dCityLongitude = Double.parseDouble((sRawRecord.substring(72, 81)).trim());
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        dCityLongitude = 0.0;
    }
    sCityName = sRawRecord.substring(93, 124).trim();
}
public int getYear() { return nYear; }
public int getMonth() { return nMonth; }
public int getDay() { return nDay; }
public int getHour() { return nHour; }
public int getMinute() { return nMinute; }
public double getSecond() { return dSecond; }
public int getUTC() { return nUTC; }
public double getLatitude() { return dLatitude; }
public double getLongitude() { return dLongitude; }
public double getMagnitude() { return dMagnitude; }
public int getDepth() { return nDepth; }
public int getEpicentre() { return nEpicentre; }
public double getCityLatitude() { return dCityLatitude; }
public double getCityLongitude() { return dCityLongitude; }
public String getCityName() { return sCityName; }

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%4d/%2d/%2d %2d:%2d:%2.1f %d Lat/Long:%6.2f,%6.2f Mag:%3.1f     Depth:%4d %5d %6.2f:%6.2f %s", nYear, nMonth, nDay, nHour, nMinute, dSecond, nUTC,     dLatitude, dLongitude,
        dMagnitude, nDepth, nEpicentre, dCityLatitude, dCityLongitude, sCityName);
}
public static class CompareMagnitude implements Comparator<EarthquakeRecord> {
    public final static CompareMagnitude instance = new CompareMagnitude();
    public int compare(EarthquakeRecord arg0, EarthquakeRecord arg1) {
        if(arg0.dMagnitude < arg1.dMagnitude){
        return(-1);
        }
        else if(arg0.dMagnitude > arg1.dMagnitude){
        return(1);
        }
        else{
        return(0);
        }
    }
}

/** Singleton public static inner class that creates a <i>Comparator</i> object if needed; used to compare <i>EarthquakeRecord</i> objects based on <i>String</i> containing City Name */
// TODO implement the following class
public static class CompareCity implements Comparator<EarthquakeRecord> {
    public final static CompareCity instance = new CompareCity();
    public int compare(EarthquakeRecord arg0, EarthquakeRecord arg1) {return arg0.sCityName.compareTo(arg1.sCityName);}
}
/** Singleton public static inner class that creates a <i>Comparator</i> object if needed; used to compare <i>EarthquakeRecord</i> objects based on <i>nDepth</i> */
// TODO implement the following class
public static class CompareDepth implements Comparator<EarthquakeRecord> {
    public final static CompareDepth instance = new CompareDepth();
    public int compare(EarthquakeRecord arg0, EarthquakeRecord arg1) {
        if(arg0.nDepth < arg1.nDepth){
        return(-1);
        }
        else if(arg0.nDepth > arg1.nDepth){
        return(1);
        }
        else{
        return(0);
        }
    }


}}
```

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class EarthquakeDataSet<aeqrDepthSort> {

private int nNumRecordsLoaded;

private EarthquakeRecord[] aeqrOriginalOrder; 

private EarthquakeRecord[] aeqrCitySort; 

private EarthquakeRecord[] aeqrDepthSort; 

private EarthquakeRecord[] aeqrMagnitudeSort;

public EarthquakeDataSet() { }


public long loadDataFromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception {
    Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(file); 
    int nMaxNumRecords;
    do { 
        nMaxNumRecords = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Maximum     Number of Records: "));
    } while (nMaxNumRecords <= 0);

    nNumRecordsLoaded = 0; 
    long lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    aeqrOriginalOrder = new EarthquakeRecord[nMaxNumRecords]; 
    try { 
        while (nNumRecordsLoaded < nMaxNumRecords && scanInput.hasNext()) {
            String sRawRecord = scanInput.nextLine(); 
aeqrOriginalOrder[nNumRecordsLoaded++] = new EarthquakeRecord(sRawRecord); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Input failure at record: " + nNumRecordsLoaded);
    } finally {
        scanInput.close(); 
    }
    System.out.printf("Number Records Loaded: %d", nNumRecordsLoaded);
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - lStartTime; 
}
public long copyOriginalArray() {

    long lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    aeqrCitySort = Arrays.copyOf(aeqrOriginalOrder, aeqrOriginalOrder.length);

    aeqrMagnitudeSort = Arrays.copyOf(aeqrOriginalOrder, aeqrOriginalOrder.length);

    aeqrDepthSort = Arrays.copyOf(aeqrOriginalOrder, aeqrOriginalOrder.length);
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - lStartTime; 
}


public void sortNativeJava() {

    System.out.println("\nSorting with native Java Sort");
    long lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Arrays.sort(aeqrCitySort, EarthquakeRecord.CompareCity.instance);

    long lElapseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStartTime;
    System.out.println("Native Java Sort: City Name: Elapsed time: " + ((float)     lElapseTime) / 1000.0);

    lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Arrays.sort(aeqrDepthSort, EarthquakeRecord.CompareDepth.instance);

    lElapseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStartTime;
    System.out.println("Native Java Sort: Depth: Elapsed time: " + ((float)     lElapseTime) / 1000.0);

    lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Arrays.sort(aeqrMagnitudeSort, EarthquakeRecord.CompareMagnitude.instance);

    lElapseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStartTime;
    System.out.println("Native Java Sort: Magnitude: Elapsed time: " + ((float)     lElapseTime) / 1000.0);
}

public void display() {
    String[] asSortKeys = { "Original", "City Name", "Magnitude", "Depth" };
    String sReturnValue = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select array to sequence display:", "Key Sequence", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, asSortKeys, asSortKeys[0]);
    if (sReturnValue == asSortKeys[0])
        display("Original Sequence", aeqrOriginalOrder);
    else if (sReturnValue == asSortKeys[1])
        display("City Name Sequence", aeqrCitySort);
    else if (sReturnValue == asSortKeys[2])
        display("Magnitude Sequence", aeqrMagnitudeSort);
    else
        display("Depth Sequence", aeqrDepthSort);
}


private void display(String rsLabel, EarthquakeRecord[] raeqrDataSet) {
    if (raeqrDataSet == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Selected array not yet populated.");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(rsLabel);
    if (nNumRecordsLoaded < 30)
        for (int i = 0; i < nNumRecordsLoaded; ++i)
            System.out.println(raeqrDataSet[i]);
    else {
        System.out.println("First 10 records:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            System.out.println(raeqrDataSet[i]);

        System.out.println("Middle 10 records:");
        int nStart = nNumRecordsLoaded / 2 - 5;
        int nEnd = nStart + 10;
        for (int i = nStart; i < nEnd; ++i)
            System.out.println(raeqrDataSet[i]);

        System.out.println("Last 10 records:");
        for (int i = nNumRecordsLoaded - 10; i < nNumRecordsLoaded; ++i)
            System.out.println(raeqrDataSet[i]);
    }
}


public String toString1() { return "Number of Records: " + nNumRecordsLoaded; }
 private int[] data; 
   private static final Random generator = new Random();

   public MergeSort( int size )
   {
      data = new int[ size ]; 

      for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
         data[ i ] = 10 + generator.nextInt( 90 );
   } 

   public void sort()
   {
      sortArray( 0, data.length - 1 ); 
   } 
   private void sortArray( int low, int high ) 
   {

      if ( ( high - low ) >= 1 ) 
      {
         int middle1 = ( low + high ) / 2; 
         int middle2 = middle1 + 1; 

         System.out.println( "split:   " + subarray( low, high ) );
         System.out.println( "         " + subarray( low, middle1 ) );
         System.out.println( "         " + subarray( middle2, high ) );
         System.out.println();

         sortArray( low, middle1 ); 
         sortArray( middle2, high );


         merge ( low, middle1, middle2, high );
      } 
   } 

   private void merge( int left, int middle1, int middle2, int right ) 
   {
      int leftIndex = left;
      int rightIndex = middle2; 
      int combinedIndex = left; 
      int[] combined = new int[ data.length ]; 

      System.out.println( "merge:   " + subarray( left, middle1 ) );
      System.out.println( "         " + subarray( middle2, right ) );

      while ( leftIndex <= middle1 && rightIndex <= right )
      {
         if ( data[ leftIndex ] <= data[ rightIndex ] )
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ leftIndex++ ]; 
         else 
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ rightIndex++ ];
      }
      if ( leftIndex == middle2 )
         while ( rightIndex <= right )
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ rightIndex++ ];
      else 
         while ( leftIndex <= middle1 ) 
            combined[ combinedIndex++ ] = data[ leftIndex++ ];      

      for ( int i = left; i <= right; i++ )
         data[ i ] = combined[ i ];


      System.out.println( "         " + subarray( left, right ) );
      System.out.println();
   } 

   public String subarray( int low, int high )
   {
      StringBuilder temporary = new StringBuilder();


      for ( int i = 0; i < low; i++ )
         temporary.append( "   " );


      for ( int i = low; i <= high; i++ )
         temporary.append( " " + data[ i ] );

      return temporary.toString();
   } 

   public String toString()
   {
      return subarray( 0, data.length - 1 );
   }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking questions on SO, please keep your code consise and show only what is required as it is quite difficult for those answering to read and understand your entire code. Also you'll get answers faster!

Comment: ah okay sorry about that and thank you for the tip

Comment: Please help me understand your object here. What exactly you mean be `sort array of references from EarthquakeRecord`? Do you mean you want to use `EarthquakeRecord[]` in place of `int[]`? If yes, which comparator method, do you want to use?

Comment: yes i would like t o use the earthquakerecord[] and i would like to do it with all the comparators that ive created in the EarthquakeRecord. I know that if i learn to do it with once its just a matter of copying and pasting for the other two. So doing it with any one of the comparators is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you turn your sorting from ints to objects with a custom comparator, you have to replace your comparison

```
if ( data[ leftIndex ] <= data[ rightIndex ] )
```

with something like

```
if ( cmp.compare(data[ leftIndex ], date[ rightIndex ]) <= 0 )
```

You probably want to use generics for this, which means your class would be `MergeSort<T>`, the array to sort would be a `T[]` (or a `List<? extends T>`) and your comparator a `Comparator<? super T>`. You might also provide a static method like the one for [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) you use in your `sortNativeJava` code.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, this is what i have tried to do but im getting one error

Comment: if ( EarthquakeRecord.CompareMagnitude.compare(data[ leftIndex ] <= data[ rightIndex ] <= 0 ));

Comment: what it says is the operator <= is not defined for the argument types earthquakerecord, earthquakerecord

Comment: Your code is broken in at least three ways. 1. `compare` is not a static method, and neither should it be. So the `cmp` object in my example would be an actual object, created e.g. using `new EarthquakeRecord.CompareMagnitude()`. 2. The arguments to `compare` should be separated by `,` not `<=`. 3. The `<= 0` goes *after* the closing parenthesis of the `compare` call. `compare` takes two arguments, and returns an integer, and it is that integer which you compare against zero. I realize that I forgot one closing parenthesis in my answer, which might have caused this.

Comment: Thank you very much I believe I got it working after playing around with it and taking into account your advice thanks so much for the help.